# Retrieving Contact photo?

Tags: java, android

I can't get photo from contacts and put it in the List View, I organise that in HashMap.
When some of the contacts don't have photo, I want to display default photo.
I am not getting any photo right now.

Here is my code:

```
cOznaci = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cbOznaci);    
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mapa = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();    
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if(cur.getCount() > 0){
            while(cur.moveToNext()){
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                long id2 = Long.parseLong(id);
                Object slika = loadContactPhoto(cr, id2);
                if(Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0){

                    final Cursor numCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "  = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                    for(numCur.moveToFirst(); !numCur.isAfterLast(); numCur.moveToNext()){

                        brTel = numCur.getString(numCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        ime = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                        tmpIme = new String[] {ime};

                        for(int i = 0; i < tmpIme.length; i++){

                            HashMap<String, Object> imeMapa = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            imeMapa.put("imeLista", ime);
                            imeMapa.put("checkBox", slika);
                            imeMapa.put("Mobilni", brTel);
                            mapa.add(imeMapa);
                        }

                    }
                    numCur.close();

                } // End if

            } // While
        }

        SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mapa, R.layout.imenik, new String[] {"imeLista", "checkBox", "Mobilni"}, new int[] {R.id.tvImeImenik, R.id.cbOznaci, R.id.tvSamoProba});
        lImenik.setAdapter(sa);

            }
        });

    } // onCreate

    public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id) { 
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id); 
        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
         if (input == null) {  
          return null;

         }
         return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign Bitmaps to ImageViews through a SimpleAdapter like that, you can only assign automatically with strings and integers. You will need to create a `ViewBinder` to do more complex assignments.

However, I suggest *not* using that level-14 API and use the PHOTO_URI instead. That's a String and SimpleAdapter's default ViewBinder should do the right thing.

Comment: In your 'while' loop, fetch the photo URI via 'String photoUri = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI));'. You can then don't need to call loadContactPhoto() and can pass that to your SimpleAdapter instead of the Bitmap.